# Unable to import Out of disk space. Unable to write content to file. File: /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/uploads error

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2, migration, bitnami, htdocs

Unable to import
Out of disk space. Unable to write content to file. File: /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/6-600x338.jpg

How do I resolve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitnami Engineer here. The error is clear in the information you posted, you ran out of space. In order to increase the disk size, go to the AWS Console, identify the instance and stops it. After that, you will need to get the information about the volume it's using

[image]

modify the size.

[image]

and start the instance again later.

You can find more information in our documentation

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/how-to/modify-ebs-volume/